# How to view assembly code in codeblocks?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, codeblocks, mingw-w64

I want to see the assembly version of my `C` code and I've learned that `-S` option can show it but I get this error when using that option:

```
cannot specify -o with -c, -S or -E with multiple files
```

The only compiler options I have used besides that one are: `-m64` and `-Wfatal-errors`. I use the `Codebloc::Blocks` IDE and `mingw64` compiler. The source file is `a43.c` and I inserted the option in this place:

[image]

Am I doing it right? I prefer using the GUI instead of command line.

Comment: I don't think that's going to work.  Try invoking the compiler directly from the console.

Comment: You want to see it when debugging? or after

Comment: Never mind, I got it working using command line.

Comment: Related: [How to remove “noise” from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output) for compiler options to give nicer asm (and don't forget `-O3` if you want non-braindead code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler options:

```
-c  # compile only (don't link)
-S  # assemble only (don't compile or link)
-E  # preprocess only (don't assemble, compile or link)
```

are mutually exclusive. Furthermore, you cannot specify:

```
-o foo.o    # write output to `foo.o`
```

if you are specifying multiple input source files.

You are adding `-S a43.c` to the **Other compiler options**. That means you
are adding them to the existing compilation options for your project. Those
options already include `-c` by default, because that's the option to *compile*,
so adding `-S` conflicts with `-c`.

`-S` does not take any argument, specifically no filename argument. It tells
`gcc` only to assemble (not compile or link) the input files, *whatever they are*. So adding:

```
-S a43.c
```

as well as adding `-S` to the existing options, adds an input file,
`a43.c`, to the project's compiler options. But of course Code::Blocks will add the
name of an input file to the compiler options whenever it compiles one of the
files in the project. So there will be *two* source filenames in the commandline.
Hence the error:

```
cannot specify -o with -c, -S or -E with multiple files
```

If you want to modify your Code::Blocks compilation options so that they will *also*
produce the assembly listing of each file compiled, then remove

```
-S a43.c
```

from **Other compiler options** and replace it with

```
-save-temps
```

Then, whenever gcc compiles a file `foo.c` in the project, it will save the
intermediate files as:

```
foo.s   # The assembly
foo.i   # The preprocessed source
```

These files will be saved in the same directory as `foo.c` itself; not in the
directory where the object file `foo.o` is output.

See [the documentation of `-save-temps` in the GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux, You can make use of the gcc to compile the code,
and **objdump -M intel -D a.out** where a.out is your compile code, and the -M intel is to output into intel syntax or remove the -M intel.
But you can also make use of **gcc -S code.c -o asm_code** in other to see the assembly language output.

Comment: `mingw64` is a windows compiler

Comment: Of course, mingw comes with `objdump` and (I think) the rest of binutils so this general idea is applicable.